# Wordpress & Vanity User URLs

Tags: php, wordpress, url, dns, subdomain

Was wondering if anyone had any smart approaches to creating dynamic vanity user urls upon user registration. My site basically uses emails as usernames. I have the regex to strip the text before the "@" symbol (e.g. "name@email.com" becomes "name") I would then like to take the "name" and create a vanity url (e.g. domain.com/name or name.domain.com)

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this with Wordpress? I'm a pretty advanced Wordpress user and my first thoughts were to do the following

1. Verify user registration
2. Upon successful user registration create page name with username as the title (this would help me achieve the www.domain.com/username)
3. Apply preset template to that page with the desired view

Any and all thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out on my own. Just create a post like you normally would and but set the post type to page. Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [wordpress author slug plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/author-slug/), it seems to do (almost exactly) that?